# How does this target is targetting the other element?

Tags: javascript, dom, data-visualization, target

I have a question about targetting other element than it pointing the element clicked in the following code.

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/gOpQdzV

I don't get this part below.

```
const addClassToStrings = addClassToEach(strings, className);

    btn.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
      if (addClassToStrings.next().done)
        el.target.classList.add(className);
    });
```

If the addClassToEach event is tied into the button, 
I assumed .classList.add(className) event would apply to the button itself.
Because it is targetting it.

I guess el.target..... this part does something.
Can anyone help me to understand this part?

DEMO:

```js
const strings = document.querySelectorAll('.string');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const className = 'darker';

function* addClassToEach(elements, className) {
  for (const el of Array.from(elements))
    yield el.classList.add(className);
}

const addClassToStrings = addClassToEach(strings, className);

btn.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
  if (addClassToStrings.next().done)
    el.target.classList.add(className);
});
```

```css
.string{width:50vmin;height:8vmin;margin:4vmin;transition:.3s ease;background:#90ee90}.string.darker{background:#343434;filter:blur(3vmin)}#btn{position:absolute;padding:5vmin 10vmin;color:#d6d6d6;font-size:8vmin;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;user-select:none;background:#3749a2;border-radius:5%;top:5vmin;left:80vmin;transition:.3s ease;cursor:pointer}#btn:active,#btn:hover{border-radius:50%;box-shadow:1vmin 1vmin 1vmin grey}#btn.darker{border-radius:0;background:#343434;filter:blur(3vmin)}
```

```html
<div class="string"></div>
<div class="string"></div>
<div class="string"></div>
<div class="string"></div>
<div class="string"></div>
<div class="string"></div>
<div class="string"></div>
<div class="string"></div>

<div id="btn">Click me</div>
```

Comment: Inside `btn` click, why you have the code `if (addClassToStrings.next().done)` ?

Comment: Every time you call `.next()` your generator function adds the class name to another one of the elements found in the initial `.querySelectorAll()`. Your code is doing exactly the things that you told it to do.

Comment: Also your code should be posted **here**, not in a linked codepen. Stack Overflow has its own facilities for creating demonstration code.

Comment: @Pointy Understood, I just tried to make my posting succint to focus on the part I'm wondering about especially, but I understand, for future, I will try to put everything within my posting. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Pointy However, what is happening is that changes the color of string not a button how did this happen?

Comment: Look at your generator function! Each `yield` adds the class name to one of the elements, and it does that without any regard to what element was involved in the event.

Comment: Got ya!!! thank you sooooo much!!!!!! I was misunderstanding that it has something to do with .target !!! how stupid I am !!